# iOS AVPlayer not able to pause after rewind/fastforward

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

**Scenario**

- If AVPlayer is playing a video, rewind for 15s and continue playback.
- If AVPlayer is paused, rewind for 15s and remain in a paused state.

**Issue**

I am unable to pause the video after `seekToTime:` is called.

**Question**

How to pause the player after calling seekToTime?

I have tried both `[Avplayer pause]` as well as setting `Avplayer.rate` to `0`. Nothing stops the video after calling `seekToTime`.

**My code**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
.
.
.
@synthesize player
.
.
.
- (IBAction)rewind:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"rewind called");

    int secToRewind = DEFAULT_REWIND_SEC;
    int time = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime) - secToRewind;
    CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, 1);
    CMTime tolerance = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1);

    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    int playerRate = player.rate;
    [player seekToTime:newTime toleranceBefore: tolerance toleranceAfter: tolerance completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSLog(@"seekToTime called");

        __strong __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (playerRate == 0) {
            [player pause];
        }

    }];


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. May I suggest an awesome library? ```pod 'FreeStreamer'```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code causing the autoplay. There was an observer attached to the player. Whenever the player item is in `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, the player was set to play that item regardless of play/pause state.

Code with fixes

```
case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay: {

            if ([playButton isSelected]) {
                 [self.player play];
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'd guess is within the buffering of the content, since you are going X (15 supposedly) seconds back, that's a lot and it needs a little bit of time to buffer the content.

Try the following code...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
.
.
.
@synthesize player
.
.
.
- (IBAction)rewind:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"rewind called");

    int secToRewind = DEFAULT_REWIND_SEC;
    int time = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime) - secToRewind;
    CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, 1);
    CMTime tolerance = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1);

    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    int playerRate = player.rate;
    [player seekToTime:newTime toleranceBefore: tolerance toleranceAfter: tolerance completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {



        do {

          NSLog(@"Successful rewind");

         __strong __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
         if (playerRate == 0) {
             [player playAt:[player currentTime]];
         }

       } while (completed == true);

    }];


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was not clear so I have updated the question. I am unable to pause the player after calling `seekToTime:`. I need to pause it if the player is paused and the user clicks on the rewind button. it should move back and remain in the paused state.